# Is Quasar and Comsat worth of replacing Ktor?

Tags: concurrency, kotlin, quasar

I hope this question be worth of answering and well asked! I have a couple of projects using Ktor. I have studied about Quasar and I know it has Comsat for web backends. As you know, Ktor uses fiber and NIO! With this notice, does rewriting the projects with Quasar (Comsat) makes them perform much (noticeably) better than Ktor?

Comment: Nice to meet you again, :). I think you need to put your question to https://stackexchange.com/, Nobody will answer your question here.

Comment: @holi-java Why? I think it is a programming question for who have used both libraries! It is not a sysadmin question!

Comment: Indeed, stackoverflow is for the question of the specific code rather than the opinion/design.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this without knowing the details and requirements of your project.

You could start by making a feature table of both using the feature you need or might need. If there are a significant amount of features missing or that would require too much time to adapt, it might not be worth changing platform.

To compare performance the absolute best would be to write a minimal Quasar app with the features you want to test so you can directly measure the perfomance based on your needs and use-case.